# .NET Core 8 Azure AD validation generates The signature is invalid

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token

When using .NET 7 the code below runs well during bearer token validation. Unfortunately, when my Web API application is upgraded to version 8 this code doesn't run well and generates this error message:

`Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature is invalid"`

```
services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
{
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{configuration["AD:TenantId"]}/", 
        ValidateIssuer = true,

        ValidAudience = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
        ValidateAudience = true,

        SignatureValidator = delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters) { return new JwtSecurityToken(token); },
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

        RequireSignedTokens = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
}, options => configuration.Bind("AD", options));
```

Then token is generated and sent by a reactjs app. This doesn't work both locally nor published to Azure App Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who are facing the same issue here's the answer:

```
SignatureValidator = delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
{
    //NET 7
    //return new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken(token);
    //NET 8
    //return new Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken(token);
}
```

Comment: Confirmed. Thank you. I had the issue in a test. Would never turn off validations in production.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `ValidAudience` to your API's client ID or app ID URI.
The ID you have set up is Graph API's ID.
Graph uses a different signature mechanism so you won't be able to validate it.

Your API should never accept tokens meant for another API (such as Graph API).
You will also need to update your front-end to acquire the correct token with a scope defined in your application.

Comment: Means .net7 and .net8 have different validation method?

Comment: Hmm it shouldn't be. Also I just noticed your SignatureValidator, you should remove it. If that overrides validation and skips it (which I guess it didn't), it would be a massive security hole in your app.

Comment: I try not to validate everything but it still shows The signature is invalid. Downgrading to .net7 the errors disappear